# php session can not work?

Tags: php, session

search.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['sessionStart'])){    
   echo "<br>you start a session";
   $_SESSION['session']='yes';    
} else {
   $_SESSION['session']='no';    
}
```

result.php

```
session_start();
$sen=$_SESSION['session'];

echo $sen1;
if($sen='no'){
  echo $sen2;
echo '<a href="homepage.php"><br>Back to search page</a>';    
} else  {
  echo $sen3;
  echo '<a href="homepage.php?sessionStart"><br>Back to search page</a>';
}
```

As you can c, if !isset($_GET['sesssionStart'])    sen1 and sen3 will be echo,
bu sen3 will echo 'yes'

can anyone help me solvethis ?
Thank you

This is link for search.php
start a session

Comment: `if($sen=='no'){` instead `=` - `==`

Comment: May I suggest you using `$_SESSION['session'] = true` instead of `'yes'`?

Comment: what the value in $sen1?

Comment: check in if == not assign =.

Answer (score 0):

You use `if($sen='no'){`this means you set $sen as no. Use `==` instead of a single `=` for a comparisson

So:

`if($sen=='no'){`

Answer (score 0):

This is because instead of comparison you are using assignment in the line

```
if($sen='no'){     // assigning value 'no' to $sen
```

Change this line to

```
if($sen=='no'){     // comparison for equality
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($sen='no'){ to if($sen=='no'){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result.php

session_start();
//also check is required for good code writing
if(isset($_SESSION))
{
    $sen=$_SESSION['session'];
}
echo $sen1;
if($sen == 'no'){    // use == in plave of =
echo $sen2;
echo '<a href="homepage.php"><br>Back to search page</a>';


}else
{
  echo $sen3;
  echo '<a href="homepage.php?sessionStart"><br>Back to search page</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an assignment operator (`=`) instead of a comparison operator (`==`) in your `if` condition. Modify that line to

`if($sen=='no')`

Answer (score 0):

From the comment of answer owner:

> You have to validate if the session has been set or not

```
if(isset($_SESSION['session']) && $sen == 'no'){
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: You have to validate if the session has been set or not

Comment: I put your comment into your answer.